# S3 Ajax CORS Error

Tags: python, ajax, heroku, amazon-s3

I have been trying to solve this for the past few hours.

I am using the Heroku S3 python app direct upload method outlined [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python).

Basically, I have a file input which I get the file from with

```
$('#files').on('change', function() {
    var files = document.getElementById("files").files;
    var file = files[0];
    if(!file){
       return alert("No file selected.");
    }
    getSignedRequest(file);
})
```

In getSignedRequest, I make a request to my `sign_s3` route

```
function getSignedRequest(file){
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open("GET", "/sign_s3?file_name="+file.name+"&file_type="+file.type);
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState === 4){
              if(xhr.status === 200){
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                uploadFile(file, response.data, response.url);
              }
              else{
                alert("Could not get signed URL.");
              }
            }
          };
          xhr.send();
        }
```

The `sign_s3` route is defined as follows

```
@main.route('/sign_s3/')
def sign_s3():
  S3_BUCKET = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')

  file_name = request.args.get('file_name')
  file_type = request.args.get('file_type')

  s3 = boto3.client('s3')

  presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket = S3_BUCKET,
    Key = file_name,
    Fields = {"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
    Conditions = [
      {"acl": "public-read"},
      {"Content-Type": file_type}
    ],
    ExpiresIn = 3600
  )

  return json.dumps({
    'data': presigned_post,
    'url': 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (S3_BUCKET, file_name)
  })
```

The uploadFile function is defined as follows

```
function uploadFile(file, s3Data, url){
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open("POST", s3Data.url);

          var postData = new FormData();
          for(key in s3Data.fields){
            postData.append(key, s3Data.fields[key]);
          }
          postData.append('file', file);
          console.log(file);

          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState === 4){
              if(xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 204){
                document.getElementById("preview").src = url;
                document.getElementById("avatar-url").value = url;
              }
              else{
                alert("Could not upload file.");
              }
           }
          };
          xhr.send(postData);
        }
      });
```

My bucket CORS config is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:5000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

But I keep getting the following error upon fileUpload

```
Failed to load https://mhealth-beta-1.s3.amazonaws.com/: Redirect from 'https://mhealth-beta-1.s3.amazonaws.com/' to 'https://mhealth-beta-1.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is mentioning a redirect. I'm not familiar with how 302 redirects interact with CORS but try this:

In your backend route, use the dns name *including* the region.

so `'https://%s.s3.%s.amazonaws.com/%s' % (S3_BUCKET, region, file_name)`

Comment: That is a good catch -- redirection is indeed unexpected, and this should at least eliminate a potential problem, but note that `s3-${region}.amazonaws.com` is not valid for all regions.  Only older regions used that format.  Newer regions use a dot rather than a dash after `s3`, and us-east-1 uses `s3-external-1`.  Currently the only consistent pattern valid everywhere is `bucket.s3.dualstack.${region}.amazonaws.com`.  I have always worked from the assumption that `localhost` is not a valid origin for CORS testing, since it is not a real domain.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the dot notation is supported everywhere, although this is not explicitly documented. In any case,  this is not OPs issue.

Comment: Yes, they appear to have been rolling out new SSL certs to older regions to support dot notation, but it has not historically been that way, and is not (yet) documented that way at [regions and endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region).  Agreed, though... that's not the problem, here.